# SQL Calculations for budgeting

Tags: sql, pivot, calculated-columns

I have a database that contains the following columns:
Vendor, Amount, StartDate, Months

I would like to be able to calculate the average monthly amount based on the Months that are entered. I would also like to see it calculate out from the start date to the end date based on the StartDate + Months calculation. The resulting table would look something like this:

Vendor1 has 2 months of 1112 starting Jan 1 while Vendor2 has 3 months of 2040 staring Feb 1

```
|       | ANNUAL | JAN   |  FEB  |  MAR  | APR   | 
Vendor1 |  2,224 | 1,112 | 1,112 |       |       |
Vendor2 |  6,120 |       | 2,040 | 2,040 | 2,040 |
```

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag back for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange DB design. However, here's what you've got to try:

```
SELECT (Amount * Months) AS Annual, (Case @(StartDate < DATE("01.02.year")) WHEN 1 THEN Amount ELSE NULL) AS Jan FROM Table --etc for all months
```

Will think of modifications though, because this way is a little too straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You would use conditional aggregation.  Assuming the start dates are all in the same year, the code might look like this:

```
select vendorid, (amount * months) as total,
       (case when month(startdate) <= 1 and month(startdate) + months >= 1
             then amount
        end) as jan,
       (case when month(startdate) <= 2 and month(startdate) + months >= 2
             then amount
        end) as feb,
       (case when month(startdate) <= 3 and month(startdate) + months >= 3
             then amount
        end) as mar,
       (case when month(startdate) <= 4 and month(startdate) + months >= 4
             then amount
        end) as apr,
from t;
```